# Difference between 2 Dates not calculating time difference

Tags: java, date

I request a Date in a Controller with

```
@GetMapping(path = "/{terminal}/{date}",consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public ServiceResponse appointmentsListDate(@PathVariable Long terminal, @PathVariable @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") Date date) {
```

Then I need to compare that Date with a stored date in database (type = timestamp without time zone).

I´m using the methods before() and after() but it fails when comparing the time part (the date comparison is good, but it doesn´t compare the time).

```
public Collection<EntrySlot> getAppointment( Date date) {
     Collection<EntrySlot> entrySlotList=new ArrayList<>();
     for(int i=0; i<appointmentList.size();i++){
          Appointment appointment = ((List<Appointment>)appointmentList).get(i);
          EntrySlot entrySlot = appointment.getIdEntrySlot();
          if (date.before(entrySlot.getStartDate())){
               entrySlotList.add(entrySlot);
          }
    return entrySlotList
  }
```

At example of the entrySlot.getStartDate stored in db is 2021-05-01 16:00:00. My date is 2021-05-01 17:00:00 and when using the `date.before(entrySlot.getStartDate)` the result is true.

I don´t know if the problem is related to the date formatting.

Thanks in advance!

PD: I have solved the problem. The hour stored in the database has GMT+2 hours. I had to substract those hour and now I can calculate the difference even using the deprecated date.util.

Comment: Can you post your code where you instantiate both dates? A minimal executable example would be nice.

Comment: Both `Date` classes are terrible, both supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes. Search Stack Overflow to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

`java.util.Date` is a lie; it does not represent dates. It presents moments in time.

'timestamp without timezone' is something completely different. You're asking the system: Hey, I have this apple. Is it better than this pear?

It'd have been better all around if the code had failed to compile but for complicated reasons, it does compile. Nevertheless, it is gobbledygook.

First, compare all the times you have into the data type that properly represents the concept of 'timestamp without timezone', which is `java.time.LocalDateTime`.

Most DB engines can give you this directly; at the JDBC level, call `.getObject(idxOrColName, LocalDateTime.class)`. A few rusty old JDBC drivers can't do this, in which case you're forced to call e.g. `.getTimestamp`, which will convert a timestamp-without-timezone in-flight to a moment-in-time-devoid-of-context, and you then have to unconvert this messed up conversion, preferably ASAP.

Once you have that, put your target in terms of LocalDateTime as well, and now compare the two. If it fails *now*, you can just debug each process individually, because then one of the two processes that end in you having an instance of LDT, is broken and it is instantly obvious which one: It's the one where printing that LDT does not show what you expected.

NB: All date/time related classes in java.util, java.sql, and the (Gregorian)Calendar class are obsolete and bad API which lead to exactly the problems you have now. Don't use those, or if you're forced into it, convert them to a `java.time` type immediately and debug this conversion on its own before continuing with the program.